# How to getendpoints of a composite partition key which has blob datatype in it

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I have a select query which is timing out, so i tried querying it using consistency all with tracing enabled, so that read_repair will fix it but that didn't helped much and at consistency all i was getting 3 responses out of 9; so i have decided to identify partition and run a repair on it but when i ran getendpoints on composite partition key which has blob datatype it is throwing an exception "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Non-hex characters" i also tried using token from cql select statement which also timing out. How can i identify the partition and repair it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just run a repair all partitions will be fixed. To repair an individual partition just read it with `CL.ALL` and read repairs will fix any differences.

That said.

`nodetool getendpoints` takes a *token* not a partition key. The murmur3 partitioner expects a long token so a large blob wont work. You can get it with CQL with something like a

```
select token(k1, k2 ...) from table where ...
```

and it will give you the token. Alternatively you can get the token from most of the drivers (java driver: `cluster.getMetadata().newToken(string)`) or from the Cassandra's java api itself (`new Murmur3Partitioner().getToken(bytebuffer)`)

Comment: i tried cql as mentioned in problem statement but the query is timing out. Looks like the only way to get through is from driver, but the driver its self is seeing timeouts  when querying that partition for select statement, will give a try and see if that helps.

Comment: it timing out is more likely due to being a wide partition or too many tombstones fwiw, not very likely that repairing it will help. Try the query with `TRACING ON`

Comment: yeah i suspect the same but the problem is since the query is timing out even enabling tracing isn't much helpful.

Comment: To check for the most likely issue, check the gc logs and system logs. `nodetool cfstats` and check the max partition size for your table. If its huge you may need to just bump your heap to be able to read it but even that has limits.